# covert list of integers to string

Tags: python, list, type-conversion

I want to convert a list to string e.g `list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]`

would be `list = '1234567890'`

I tried `''.join()` but this doesn't  work since the list consists of integers

Comment: `''.join(str(x) for x in list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert each item to string first
`''.join(str(x) for x in list)`

Answer (score 0):

As you have a list of `int` `values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]` (don't use builtin `list` for naming) you may convert them to `str` before with

- a generator expression

  ```
  result = ''.join(str(x) for x in values)
  ```
- `map` function

  ```
  result = ''.join(map(str, values))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
lst=[1,3,2,4,4]
list_string=''

for i in lst:
    list_string+=str(i)
print(list_string)
```

note: you can not use list as variable.